# How to block files only in folder1 directory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Structure:

```
./project/
├── folder1/
    ├── folder2/
        ├── test.php
        ├── abc_123.xml
    ├── test.php
    ├── abc_123.xml
├── .htaccess
```

/.htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "^\/folder1\/[a-z0-9_]+\.(php|log|xml)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

My code is not working. Doesn't block anything

UPD1:
If I use this code, then files in all nested directories are also blocked. But I need to block only in "/folder1/".

```
<FilesMatch "^[a-z0-9_]+\.(php|log|xml)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Note that [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) says: You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that .htaccess support is turned on for your HTTP server in the first place?

Comment: And that you granted its content to override the central configuration ("AllowOverride" directive) ...

Comment: Not sure why you are escaping slashes in your pattern. Also not sure what exactly `FilesMatch` matches _against_ - if that even _is_ the full URL request path, or just the file name with the path already stripped off? (Can't find anything definitive about that in the documentation.)

Comment: I added "UPD1" to the post. @Quentin

Comment: _"If I use this code, then files in all nested directories are also blocked."_ - because that same configuration gets applied on all lower folders as well, I suppose. _"But I need to block only in `/folder1/`."_ - not sure if you can do it that way, with FilesMatch. If you have mod_rewrite available, then I would probably do this with a RewriteRule that uses the `F` flag.